# Replace http:// in anchor portion of links using Jquery

Tags: jquery, class, replace, hyperlink, anchor

on a page there a several links of:

```
<a class="linked" href="http://link1.com>http://link1.com</a>

<a class="linked" href="http://link2.com>http://link2.com</a>
```

How would one remove the second http:// in each link so it can't be seen on the screen.

I've tried this to no avail:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.linked').html().replace("http://","");
```

Comment: Are you trying to remove it from the href or from the text?

Comment: trying to remove it from the text, thx.

Answer (score 3):

If you are talking about the visible text in an anchor tag

```
$.each($('.linked'), function()
{
  var anchor = $(this);
  anchor.text( anchor.text().replace("http:\/\/",'') )
});
```

Missing ');' at the end...

Comment: Why `$.each($('.linked'), ...` instead of `$('.linked').each(...`?

Comment: They're equivalent -- personal preference.

Comment: The way I wrote it works with other kinds of collections, not just jquery collections. So I tend to write them that way.

Comment: Neither of these had the desired effect, did nothing:  
$('.linked').each(function() 
{
  var anchor = $(this);
  anchor.text( anchor.text().replace("http:\/\/",'') );
});


$.each($('.linked'), function()
{
  var anchor = $(this);
  anchor.text( anchor.text().replace("http:\/\/",'') )
});

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, the jQuery-less version:

```
var links = document.links;
for(var i = links.length; i--; ) {
    with(links[i]) {
        if(/(^|\s)linked(\s|$)/.test(className)) {
            firstChild.nodeValue =
                firstChild.nodeValue.replace(/^http:\/\//, '');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: okay, that didn't work either when placed in the head or body.

Comment: @adrian33: the links must exist before you can modify them, ie you have to put the script element as last element of the body, use jQuery's `ready()` function, `window.onload` or `DOMContentLoaded`