# Replace hard-coded anchor portion of multiples link

Tags: javascript, html, iis-7

This question is similar (but has a different twist) to [Replace http:// in anchor portion of links using Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/638488/replace-http-in-anchor-portion-of-links-using-jquery)

My goal would be to come up with an optimal solution to replace absolute paths / implement relative paths in a web site, perhaps using a scripting technique (jQuery or JsRender) or other relevant technique

There are:
- many distinct hard-coded server names or IPs (even over 10 ) may exist within each page
- over 1000+ .htm, .html pages to massage

Your thoughs are welcome (as well a short how to!)

AgileQ

Comment: You probably want to do it serverside, not in clientside JS? Do you want to convert them only once, or do you want to replace the protocols for each distinct request?

Comment: Let me describve further. Links in a page are like <a href="http://<servername>/the rest of the path>"/<a>. The protocol could possible change over time. So my thought was to use a variable to replace the server name, and there could be up to 10 different servers (variables) involved. My problem is really that the server names will change over time due documents relocation to other servers and I want to make a true test environment.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I'd cook a jQuery solution:

```
$('a[href^="http"]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();      
    var matches = $(this).attr('href').match(/http(s?):\/\/[^\/]+(\/.*)$/);
    window.location = matches[2];
});
```

Note: I have not tested this, and there's likely a flaw in my regex pattern. (I never get them right first time, but I'm not in a position to test this at the moment)

But the point is to catch clicks on links with http & domain specified, then use javascript's .match() on the href of the clicked link, providing a sub-match for the portion of the href that represents the path. then redirect to that. I would have used a positive look behind in the regex, but JavaScript doesn't support that.

**update** I just tested the regex here http://jsfiddle.net/2wmaM/ and it seems to work.

Comment: Ok. I do get the /world. That's fine. Yet I have to repeat several times change for ex:  http://10.4.22.9/world to another IP that would be provided by some array. Not sure I want to do that. How about if I have a .js file that would contain the array of server names and have a variable in the a href that would refer to it? Ex: servernameA = "http://10.5.22.44:82" and the variable in the link would substitue it dynamically by using a script that gets executed on page load?

Comment: Then I just need to call the script once per page, loop to do string interpolation on all links (not all the same url)

Comment: @Agileot sure I understand -- the expression will take care of *any* link having protocol and domain specified, regardless of which domain is on that link. That, of course could be problematic if you have legitimate external links you would not like to be re-written.